# Remove all diacritics without script with a single formula for use in all cells without making calls to Google API

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I created a formula that removes diacritics but needs to make calls through an `ImportDATA`. If I use this formula on every cell I need, it will exceed the call limit I can make. And it will lock the spreadsheet.

`=ArrayFormula(if(exact(A1,Upper(A1)),Upper(VLOOKUP(A1,split(trim(transpose(split(query(SUBSTITUTE(regexreplace(regexreplace(query(IMPORTDATA("https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html"),"Select Col1 where Col1 contains '<td'",),"<td class=.+>","")&"~"&MOD(ROW(A:A),4),".+~[01]$",""),"~3","@"),"",9^6),"@"))),"~2"),2,0)),split(trim(transpose(split(query(SUBSTITUTE(regexreplace(regexreplace(query(IMPORTDATA("https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html"),"Select Col1 where Col1 contains '<td'",),"<td class=.+>","")&"~"&MOD(ROW(A:A),4),".+~[01]$",""),"~3","@"),"",9^6),"@"))),"~2")))`

Instead of making this call to `ImportDATA`, I would like to use column A to put the diacritics and column B the corresponding common letters ... So make changes without having to make calls outside the spreadsheet and also without having to of creating a new Script function that is also often used, has a google limit that blocks usage ... But as I created this formula with the help of 3 answers here from StackOverflow, now to make this change I'm not succeeding.

And preferably that this formula already made the changes in a complete column instead of converting one cell only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(L2:L, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, J2:J),
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(L2:L, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, J2:J)), J2:K, 2*
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A)), 0)&""), L2:L)))
```

[image]

Comment: I was following every step you took on my spreadsheet ... I found it spectacular, congratulations and thank you for your willingness to help ... Honestly? Of all the options for removing diacritics, this is the best of all, way above options that require scripting and so on. There are no limitations and no spreadsheets crashing this way and I can still add as many other diacritics as I want ... I'm so grateful! @player0

Comment: I need your help mate! Thanks... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190958/remove-diacritics-via-formula-on-google-sheets-part-2