# Remove diacritics via formula on Google Sheets (Part 2)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

With the help of a StackOverflow member, we have created a way to remove diacritics from personal names, these diacritics are saved in a list and as they appear in their names, they are removed and converted to common keyboard letters.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A1000),
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A1000)), A2:B1000, 2*
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A1000)), 0)&""), C2:C)))
```

But ... What happened was that in one of the names instead of the formula converting the letter "í" to "i", it converted to "a"

I would like help finding out what happened as it is the first time this has occurred and I could not find the problem.

The name was:

```
Á. Di María
```

And converted to:

```
A. Di Maraa
```

The correct form would be:

```
A. Di Maria
```

Both diacritics are saved in the conversion list, so it's not the fault, there's something I'm missing but I don't know what it is.

I leave here the link to the spreadsheet, so you can make it easier to understand what happened:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfB8GskVU_ciFKuzae9XQF-pi3y6jsYtsanN46vmNOs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(
 SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), " ", "♥")), REPT("(.)", 
        LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(
 SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), " ", "♥")), REPT("(.)", 
        LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), LOWER(A:B), 1, 0), VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(
 SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), " ", "♥"), REPT("(.)", 
        LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), LOWER(A:B), 2, 0)), REGEXEXTRACT(
 SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), " ", "♥"), REPT("(.)", 
        LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))))),,999^99)), " ", ), "♥", " ")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Mate, Could you explain to me why in the formula for finding the diacritics in ```column E```, he could not find the ```í``` of the word ```María```? Thanks again!

Comment: use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), 
 REPT("(.)", LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), 
 "['A-Za-z\.-]", )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2uiu.png

Comment: or if you want unique list in E column use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), 
 REPT("(.)", LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), 
 "['A-Za-z\.-]", )),,999^99)),,999^99), " "))))`