# Google Sheets - Text replacement based on list (not entire cell)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, find-replace

I have a list of student names in a set of cells. For example:

In cell L2, it says: 
Jones, Thomas. 
Lewis, Marta. 
James, Jessica. 
Annis, Jennifer. 
Bones, Raymond. 
(each name on a separate line in that same cell)

In cell L2, it says:
James, Jessica. 
Bones, Ray. 
Lewis, Marta.
Davidson, Joanna.
Field, Jennifer. 
(again, each name on a separate line in that same cell)

And so forth for more than 150 cells in that column.

All of the affected cells are in column L (they are created from a concatenated list - so they are the result of a different formula).

Some students have nicknames that are inputted by some teachers but not others.  I need to write a script that includes one name and tells it anytime it is found, replace it with the other name (for about 38 different names).

I have been trying to copy/paste from other people's scripts that seemed useful, but I've gotten frustrated and deleted all of them:

I have tried to create a long script that included:
var to_replace = "James, Jessica"; var replace_with = "James, Jessie";
var to_replace = "Bones, Raymond"; var replace_with = "Bones, Ray"; (all 38 names)

and one that included:
replaceinsheet(sheet,'James, Jessica','James, Jessie'); replaceinsheet(sheet,'Bones, Raymond','Bones, Ray'); (all 38 names)

and one that listed them this way: replaceInSheet(values, 'James, Jessica', 'James, Jessie');

I've tried using Substitute and RegEx expressions, but that doesn't like the fact that there are several names in the same cell.  And I must maintain that structure because lots of other sheets are depending on that one.

I'm stuck. Can someone please help?

I've created a sample sheet to hopefully show what I'm talking about:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15lt4zQzupz-ppBQlcCC9uABpYD3nKKCdE78ezOJfXNA/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated
Details
Sheets,  Mac OS, Education

Comment: non-scripted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734110/5632629

Comment: That is working great at pulling in the nicknames!  Thanks!  But it is not pulling in the names that don't get modified.

For example:

Comment: For example:  The cell is:  
  
Smith, John. 
Smith, Jane. 
Jones, Tom. 
Adcock, Thomas. 
  
My lookup columns include. 
Smith, Jane -->. Smith, Janie. 
Adcock, Thomas --> Adcock, Tommy. 
  
Those changes are being made.  
But the resulting cell now only contains THOSE names, when I would like it to contain:  
  
Smith, John. 
Smith, Janie. 
Jones, Tom. 
Adcock, Tommy. 
  
Is this possible?

Comment: I have still been playing with it... On my sample sheet, I've managed to get one name to change and to pull in all the other names, but now it only changes the one name.

The formula you suggested is in Column O.  I feel like I must be doing something silly wrong.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15lt4zQzupz-ppBQlcCC9uABpYD3nKKCdE78ezOJfXNA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi, have you solved it? From your spreadsheet i can see how the nicknames Tommy, Jessie and Ray are working. If your issue is solved please create an answer and mark it so everyone can benefit from it. If not, can you edit the question with the current situation?