# Bulk find-and-replace regexs in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace

Is there a function, script, or add-on that can apply a large series of regex replacements to a range of data in Google Sheets? I have one sheet with a list of addresses and another with several dozen pairs of regular expressions in two columns (e.g. "St.$" and "Street"), and I want to replace all instances of the first column of phrases in the address list with the corresponding phrase in the other.

This question was initially closed as being answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733434/remove-all-diacritics-without-script-with-a-single-formula-for-use-in-all-cells), but even after some significant tweaking to fit my situation, I can only get that formula to replace one phrase per address, and any other matching phrases will be replaced by the first word (so "1234 N. Main St." becomes "1234 North Main North" instead of "1234 North Main Street"). Is there a method that specifically doesn't do that?

Comment: Could you give an example with some data that shows the sheet with the list of address, the sheet with the pairs of regular expressions? It would also help to see how you tried to solve it, what you got and what you expected to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your data is in a single column, here's a script (much cleaner and more extensible than the formula approach):

Note: this is not an in-place replacement.

```js
function processColumn(column)
{
  // Add more as needed:
  // [Regex, Replacement]
  let replaceTable = 
  [
    [/\bN\./g, 'North'],
    [/\bS\./g, 'South'],
    [/\bSt\./g, 'Street']
  ];

  // A column is an array of rows
  // A row is an array of values.
  return column.map(row => 
    // This is an optimization to skip over blank values
    row[0] 
      ? replaceTable.reduce(
        // Replace one value at a time, in order
        (curString, tableEntry) => curString.replace(tableEntry[0], tableEntry[1]),
        row[0]
      )
      : ''
  );
}
```

### Usage Example:

All your data is in A:A, like so:

| A |
| --- |
| 123 N. Main St. |
| 124 N. Main St. |
| 19 S. Main St. |

Then in column B:

```
=processColumn(A:A)
```

This will place all the processed values in column B:

| B |
| --- |
| 123 North Main Street |
| 124 North Main Street |
| 19 South Main Street |

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this:

```
values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
values = values.map(outer => outer.map(inner => inner
                                            .replaceAll(/\bN\./g, 'North')
                                            .replaceAll(/\bS\./g, 'South')
                                            .replaceAll(/\bSt\./g, 'Street')
                                       )
                                      );
```

Change this `values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()` to what ever you need