# Reconfigure a function using reduce to work on entire array Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, reduce

I have a function that Bulk find and replaces regexes that I repeatedly use. From here.

[Bulk find-and-replace regexs in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192335/bulk-find-and-replace-regexs-in-google-sheets)

But it only works on a single column.

I want the function to iterate through an entire array.

I have read about Reduce and came away with only the simplest of understandings. Not enough to reconfigure the function

```
function processColumn(column)
{
  // Add more as needed:
  // [Regex, Replacement]
  let replaceTable = 
  [
    [/\bN\./g, 'North'],
    [/\bS\./g, 'South'],
    [/\bSt\./g, 'Street']
  ];

  // A column is an array of rows
  // A row is an array of values.
  return column.map(row => 
    // This is an optimization to skip over blank values
    row[0] 
      ? replaceTable.reduce(
        // Replace one value at a time, in order
        (curString, tableEntry) => curString.replaceAll(tableEntry[0], tableEntry[1]),
        row[0]
      )
      : ''
  );
}
```

I know I can do this in other ways like:

```
values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
values = values.map(outer => outer.map(inner => inner
                                            .replaceAll(/\bN\./g, 'North')
                                            .replaceAll(/\bS\./g, 'South')
                                            .replaceAll(/\bSt\./g, 'Street')
                                       )
                                      );
```

How to reconfigure processColumn function to iterate through an entire array ?

Comment: Could you share the sample sheet you are working on with the sample data? Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function processColumn(values) {
  let replaceTable = [
    [/\bN\./g, 'North'],
    [/\bS\./g, 'South'],
    [/\bSt\./g, 'Street']
  ];
  return values.map(row =>
    row.map(c => c ? replaceTable.reduce((curString, tableEntry) => curString.replaceAll(...tableEntry), c) : '', "")
  );
}
```

- By this modification, 2 dimensional array is used as the argument as `values` of `processColumn(values)`.

Comment: Tanaike, I see you added an inner map, of course! Thank you!!